# Union Query or a better option

Tags: php, mysql, union, union-all

I have the following three tables and I want to pull data out of them by the `userid`, that is the one key field that gives them a relationship. I also want to pull the data in order by `timestamp` Example of the table schema is below and what I have for a union query that is not working.

```
Table1: userid, event_id, event_name, timestamp
Table2: id_user, comment, timestamp
Table3: user_id, photo, timestamp
```

---

```
 $result5 = mysql_query 
     ("(SELECT event_name, timestamp FROM table1 WHERE userid = '25')
    UNION ALL 
       (SELECT comment,timestamp FROM table2 WHERE id_user = '25')
    UNION ALL 
         (SELECT photo,timestamp FROM table3 WHERE user_id ='25')
    ORDER BY timestamp") 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: So you want to "pull" all the event_names of that user, all his comments and all his photos? If these 3 columns (`event_name`, `comment`, `photo`) are compatible (e.g. they are all `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`), yes, your query seems fine. Can you clarify how "it is not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `event_name`, `comment` and `photo` aren't related, you shouldn't be using any sort of  `UNION`. What is common among these tables is the `user_id`. You're looking for a `JOIN`. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.event_name, a.timestamp, b.comment, b.timestamp, c.photo, c.timestamp
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.id_user = a.userid
INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.user_id = a.userid
WHERE a.userid = '25'
```